# How to create a popup window in html to unlock a website

Tags: jquery, html, authentication, popup

I am creating a website (in HTML) for a kid & I want to have a popup window show up every time the website opens. This window will have simple math questions (for a 1st grader) that the user needs to answer to proceed. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a jquery plugin like colorbox to create the popup: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

As for the questions themselves, if you're just using jquery/html, I'd probably create arrays of questions and answers in json objects: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-loop-over-json-string-each-example/

Then I'd use javascript to get a random number within the array to choose which question to display.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw3av/)

It's a little rough, but basically it checks the input of the user against an `array`. If the value of the answer isn't the same as the last item in the array, the user has the answer wrong. If the answer is the same, the question box has a `class` applied to it which hides the div.